# Passing data using post in the JQuery load method

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

I'm using the following code to pass data to my view in my Django app, but for some able am not able to access it in the view. Either I'm passing it incorrectly, or am trying to access it incorrectly, and was wondering if you guys could help me out.

```
jQuery("#garbage").load(
    '/search/loadBottomLooks/',
    {'pageNum':2},
    function(responseText, responseStatus) {
        alert('got into the callback');
    }
)
```

View:

```
pageNum = request.POST['pageNum']
```

Thanks!

Comment: That looks more like a `GET` not a `POST` but i'm not familiar with Django, sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.load()` uses GET, [`$.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) is what you're looking for if you want to send a post:

```
 $.post("/search/loadBottomLooks/", 
 { pageNum: "2" },
 function(responseText, responseStatus){ 
      alert('got into the callback!'); 
      $("#garbage").html(responseText);
 });
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I wanted to load the response from that view into my #garbage element, and thats the reason I thought I should use load, and pass my data as the second argument

Comment: If you want to load the response data into #garbage, see the revised code.